# Detect German Umlaut in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

Let's say I have multiple strings. Those strings could contain german umlauts like ö,ä,ü,Ü,ß...

Id like to check if my strings have umlauts in them, e.g:

```
has_umlaut(string) # should return true or false

"BG Göttingen" -> true
"BV Chemnitz 99" -> false
"Giants Düsseldorf" -> true
"Klöß" -> true
```

Hope somebody can help me out!

Comment: BTW `ß` is not an 'umluat' :)

Comment: hehe, I know :)

But I makes me trouble anyways :/

Comment: @AndreZimpel Are your sure you have no foreign words with other accents like éêè and you have no problem with them? Perhaps `String#ascii_only?` would help you also.

Comment: @knut Good Point. It might be. My actual problem is that the website I`m crawling has 3 different encodings mixed together then rails ecnodes them to utf-8 and then I have to clear that mess up. That's why I want to check if there are umlaute (yep, with ß) in the string or not. Otherwise I would do `force_encoding("iso-8859-1").encode("utf-8")` or `encode('cp1252', :fallback => {....}).force_encoding("utf-8")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use regexp:

```
 def has_umlaut(str)
    !!(str =~ /[öäüÖÄÜß]/)
 end
```

Comment: That does not return `true` or `false`. Also, `return` is redundant.

Comment: @sawa I know. But I can write str =~ /[öäüÖÄÜß]/ into a variable and check if it's Nil or not and return true or false. Why is it redundant?

Comment: @AndreZimpel You asked for `true` and `false`. It is redundant because it works the same without it.

Comment: @Secator Your edit is not elegant. A common way is this: `!!(str =~ /[öäüÖÄÜß]/)`.

Comment: Ah okay, so !! does return by default? Cause `str =~ /[öäüÖÄÜß]/` did return a int or nil